# Is the position of "sufficient surface area" correct in "allowing large volumes of water sufficient surface area to seep back into the ground"?

Tags: grammar, word-order

I found one passage that I really cannot understand the grammar structure. The below is the problematic sentence.

> The crates feature voids, allowing large volumes of water sufficient surface area to seep back into the ground. [- Source](https://www.homebuilding.co.uk/advice/soakaways)

I think this sentence should be;
The crates feature voids with sufficient surface are, allowing large volumes of water to seep back into the ground.

I want ask why you can bring the words "sufficient surface area" suddenly between "water" and "to".

Could someone explain this grammar structure ?

Comment: Adjusted for clarity: The crates feature voids [that would be] allowing large volumes of water [a] sufficient surface area to seep back.

Comment: Thank you for very quick and helpful response!! It's all clear now!!!

Comment: Please proof-read your question, I think you mean "sufficient surface area" not "sufficient surface are"

Answer (score 3):

*Allow* is a ditransitive — “double-object” — verb here. It’s like *give* in *give a dog a bone*:

> **allow**, *v.*
> **IV.** To permit, enable.
> **11.** *transitive.* With direct and indirect object.
> **a.** To permit or enable (a person)<sup>*</sup> to have (something).
>  <sub>Source: [*Oxford English Dictionary*](https://oed.com) (login
> required)</sub>

<sub>* Note that it does not need to be “a person”; it can be any creature or insentient thing.</sub>

An example provided by the *OED* includes: *allow them free parking*.

Here’s another from the wild: *. . . allow cars enough space to enter and exit safely . . .* ([Limitless Paving & Concrete](https://limitlesspavingandconcrete.com/parking-space-dimensions/))

Applied to your sentence, then: *allow a lot of water enough surface area*.

> *The crates feature voids, [which allow] large volumes of water [enough] surface area to seep back into the ground.*

Answer (score 2):

*Allow* can mean *provide with*.

This is covered in the following definition in [Merriam-Webster](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/allow):

> **allow** 2a: to assign as a share or suitable amount (as of time or money)
> *allow an hour for lunch*

So this sentence means

> The crates feature voids, providing large volumes of water with sufficient surface area to seep back into the ground.

Comment: Wow... What a quick and perfect answer this is...I totally understood!　Super thanks !!!

Comment: @GenKurokawa The original sentence is easy to misread if you don't realize that the verb *allow* is here taking two different objects, much as *give* does in *give it time* or *give the water enough area*.